# Work around AdMob's 35-character URL limit?

Tags: android, admob

To advertise an app on AdMob, you select a “Target URL” which is where users get directed when they click on your ad. A Target URL to the Android Market might look like this:

```
market://details?id=com.example.myapplication
```

You also have to enter a “Display URL” which gives users a preview of what they will see once they click on your ad. I could see this URL being (a) the same as above, or (b) the web equivalent of:

```
market.android.com/details?id=com.example.myapplication
```

The problem is that Google institutes a 35-character limit on the Display URL, and my understanding is they are no longer accepting exception requests for this. I understand Google does this to block URLs like this:

```
www.GoogleThinksThisIsTooLong.com/HereIsEvenMore/AndMore/
```

How can I work around this without re-publishing the app with a ridiculously short package name? The generic segment “market://details?id=com.” is already 24 characters, and “market.android.com/details?id=com.” is 34 characters!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first response about using a shortened URL:

I have not actually tried that, but Google's requirement is: "The display URL's top level domain must match the landing page URL of the promoted website."

```
http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/add-your-mobile-site-or-android-app
```

And they do not allow redirection. They do go on to say: "If the URL is too long, a shortened version may be used."

So maybe they are referring to your suggestion.

Comment: You shouldn't use the answer-function to answer on a post, this is not a normal Bulletin-Board. You can use the Comments to do so. If you're unsure, you might want to contact their support via Email.

Comment: @Androider It looks like you've accidentally created two accounts. If you change this account to use the same e-mail address as the one you used originally, I can merge them easily and you'll be able to edit your question and accept an answer. Flag your question for moderator attention once you've done so.

Answer (score -1):

What about using a ShortURL Service like Twitter? There is even one powered by Google: [Goo.gl](http://goo.gl/)